# Naming repeated patterns

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, pattern-matching

How can I name a repeated pattern to apply a rule on it? 
In the example below I have two element sequence. There is no problem in naming them and then applying some function on it:

```
ClearAll[f];
SequenceReplace[{1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {a_, b_} /; b > 1.2 a :> 
  f[{a, b}]]
```

What if the length of the sequence is variable, say of size `k` with some constraint on that pattern `{_,_ ,etc}`? There is `Repeated[_, {k}]`. But how to pass it to the function `f`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing to note is that `a_` is a short hand notation. It is almost always helpful to look at the `FullForm` when you are trying to write patterns. When you do that with `a_` you will notice that it is interpreted as

```
Pattern[a, Blank[]]
```

From the [docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html), this can be written as

```
a: _
```

This provides a way to name repeated sequences, e.g.

```
a : Repeated[_, {k}] (* where k has to be a positive integer *)
c : {a_, b_}
c : {a_, b : Repeated[_, {k}]}
```

or any other pattern you wish.

As an additional note, when using `a` in

```
a : Repeated[_, {k}]
```

it is a `Sequence`, and a typical method for manipulating it is to place it inside of a `List`, e.g.

```
(* the simplest example *)
f[a : Repeated[_, {k}]] := {a}
```